# Ag-Grid - Show context menu on right click when "No rows to show"

Tags: javascript, ag-grid

I am wondering if, when a grid has no items to show, there is a way, when the user right clicks on the grid, to include the context menu in order to show an "Add row" option.

Comment: That's rather bad UX on the web - avoid right click menus as users expect them to be the context menu from the browser. Instead have a button at the bottom to add more rows, or possibly an empty row in the grid that users can save or otherwise action.

Comment: Hey Keith, thanks for the feedback. I understand the UX issue but the grid has it's own context menu when it has records. 

So showing the browser context menu, specifically, when a user has the mouse on the grid, does not add any value the user experience if the user wants to perform actions on the grid.

But, like you mentioned, if it is not possible to attach the event to the grid as I am trying to implement, adding a button will be the next step.

Again, thanks for your feedback.

Comment: That still makes it bad UX - right click menus are a hangover from desktop development. Looking at the component it very much appears to be trying to be Excel-like, in which case the best model _still_ isn't right click but to copy Excel too. Have an empty row at the bottom that users can enter data into.

Comment: @MarioAndrade did you ever find out something about this?